# Angular 2 Service not functioning as Singleton in Child Component (possible duplicate)

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, angular2-services, angular2-directives

**SECOND UPDATE**

My issue was in the service itself, changing the methods to arrow functions solved the problem.

---

This might be a repeat, but I have done exhaustive research on Angular DI and it's clear that injecting services at the root level make them available as the same instance to all components in an app.

Underneath my AppComponent I have three children Screenshot, Confirm and Preview. I call a service from the Screenshot component and save some data on that service, then try to access that data later on from the Preview component but it seems I am accessing a new instance of that service.

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Screenshot,
    Confirm,
    Preview,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    Preview
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    ScreenshotService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild(Preview) preview: Preview; 

    title: string;
    confirmed: boolean;
    constructor(
        private screenshotService: ScreenshotService,
        private messageService: MessageService,
    ) {
        this.title = 'Media Radar';
        this.confirmed = false;
    }

    onNotify(confirm): void {
        this.confirmed = confirm;
        if(this.confirmed) {
            this.preview.showPreview();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class='popup'>
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    <screenshot [hidden]="confirmed" (showConfirm)='onNotify($event)'></screenshot>
    <confirm [hidden]="!confirmed" (hideConfirm)='onNotify($event)'></confirm>
    <preview [hidden]="!confirmed"></preview>
</div>
```

**preview.component**

```
import { ScreenshotService } from './screenshot.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'preview',
    template: `<canvas #preview></canvas>`
})

export class Preview {
    @ViewChild('preview') preview: ElementRef;
    private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    constructor(
        private screenshotService: ScreenshotService,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {}

    showPreview() {
        console.log(this.screenshotService) // shows a new instance with no data
    ...
    }
}
```

To avoid getting too lengthy with code, I'll leave out the service and the other child component which calls it first but can post if needed.

**UPDATE**

**screenshot.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ScreenshotService {
    public imageURL: string = '';
    public title: string  = '';
    public height: number = 0;
    public width: number = 0;

    constructor() {
    }
    convertToBlob(): Promise<any> {
        console.log(this); // returns all the initial values above when called from the Preview component the second time despite being previously assigned values when a different method was called from a different service
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you use @Injectable() in your service?

Comment: Yes. I'll add some of the service for more context.

Comment: Can you build a plunker that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: I have an example that shows a service working across components here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing Check out the message.service.ts file in the APM-Final folder.

Comment: Where did you inject your Auth and Message services? I don't see it main.ts, app.module or app.component.

Comment: What specific Angular version were you using?

Comment: it's version 4.0.3

Comment: @DeborahK I'm not sure a plunker will be more useful than to see the full code. It's a chrome extension so you won't be able to run it correctly. Any thoughts though?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the service methods. I changed them to arrow functions and it solved everything.